# Does an employer pay payroll taxes on non-taxable wages like 401K matches?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, payroll-taxes

In addition to what the employee would pay in income tax on taxable wages an **employer** also pays their own payroll taxes on all taxable wages like:

- FICA
- FUTA
- SDI
- SUI
- ETT

Are these taxes due from the employer on 401K matches?

What about on non-taxable fringe benefits?

Comment: I didn't notice this has been answered before...

Comment: @littleadv this is **not** a duplicate because that question asks what the *employee* must pay. I am asking about what the *employer* must pay.

Comment: this is a different question. This is about what tax employER pays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> FICA

No.

> FUTA

Generally, FUTA is limited to a very low amount compared to the overall salary (first $7K a year)

> SDI

Depends on the state law, generally is also limited to a certain maximum amount.

> SUI

Same as SDI - depends on the state law.

> ETT

If you're referring to the California Employment Training tax - it is limited to the first $7K of the annual pay, same as FUTA.

Non-taxable fringe benefits are not considered wages.